# Different template specializations in friend method's argument list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, friend

I am trying to create a method taking two instances of (different) specializations of a class template and returning the value of type deduced from template specializations at compile time.

What I have so far is (in minimal case)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T> class box
{
protected:
    T value;
public:
    box(T value)
    {
        this->value = value;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, box<T>& obj)
    {
        return os << obj.value;
    }

    template<typename K> friend auto operator+(
        const box<T>& left, const box<K>& right) ->
            box<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<K>())>
    {
        typedef decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<K>()) result_type;
        return box<result_type>(left.value + right.value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    box<int> int_container = box<int>(2);
    box<float> float_container = box<float>(7.0);
    auto another_one = int_container + float_container;
    std::cout << int_container << " " << float_container << " " << another_one << std::endl;
}
```

This won't compile (by gcc) until I make the `field` value public. I suppose, the compiler cannot (or would not) treat `container<K>` as a friend with the declared operator.

Of course, I could add a public getter for `value`.

Other solution is to make all specializations of this template friends by adding `template<typename> friend class box;` to the beginning of the class definition and making operator a class member instead of `friend`. But that approach would not work in case I decide to create a `friend` method for which no such alternative is present.
(Making all specializations friends without re-defining the operator as a class member does not compile for the same reason as in the original case.)

So is there a way to make a method template a friend of all of a class template's specializations in case its template parameter is used in one of its arguments' type definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every operator needs to be a friend of every template specialization, you need to keep both template parameters free. I also found that you need to move the definition outside the class, though I'm not perfectly sure why:

```
template <typename T>
class box
{
    // ...

    template <typename A, typename B>
    friend
    auto operator+(const box<A>& left, const box<B>& right) -> box<decltype(std::declval<A>() + std::declval<B>())>;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
auto operator+(const box<A>& left, const box<B>& right) -> box<decltype(std::declval<A>() + std::declval<B>())>
{
  return { left.value + right.value };
}
```

By the way, instead of the cumbersome `auto -> decltype` construction, you could also use the simpler and more readable `box<typename std::common_type<A, B>::type>`, or in C++14 `box<std::common_type_t<A, B>>`.

Comment: Thanks. Still, I believe `std::common_type<A, B>::type` is not what is needed in this case (because the type has to be inferred not from types of operands but from result their addition produces).

Comment: @MaxKibardin: You're right, the `+` operator could be overloaded and produce completely different results.